# Finding Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Question:

Find all linear operators $T$: $\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ such that

$S\circ T=T\circ S$

for every linear operator $S$: $\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ .

I know one route would be to use matrices. Let $T$ be some 4x4 matrix, and then commute with some matrix M of mainly $0$ entries such that TM=MT, repeating this process with different M to find T by trial and error. Would this method work and if so what's the best way of going about it? Or is there a more efficient method? TIA.

Comment: Doing this with $4\times 4$-matrices is a good idea. Clearly $T$ can be plus or minus the identity matrix. You can prove that those are the only options. Take $S=E_{i,j}$, the matrix with zeroes everywhere expect at the $(i,j)$-th entry. In that spot, put a $1$. Varying $i$ and $j$ an explicitly computing all these conditions will give you the answer.

Comment: The actual solution is $\{ \lambda I : \lambda \in \Bbb R\}$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In what follows, I'll prove this for arbitrary dimension $n$ instead of $n=4$.

**Proof 1.** Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $AB=BA$ for all $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. By $e_i$ denote the $i$-th standard basis vector. Note that the $(j,i)$-th entry of $A$ is given by $e_j^\top Ae_i$. Fix $i$ and let $B = I - 2e_ie_i^\top$. Then $B = B^\top$, $Be_i = -e_i$ and $Be_j = e_j$ for any $j\neq i$. Hence, $e_j^\top ABe_i = e_j^\top BAe_i$ implies $-e_j^\top Ae_i = (Be_j)^\top Ae_i = e_j^\top Ae_i$ and thus $e_j^\top Ae_i = 0$ for all $j\neq i$. Since $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ was arbitrary, this means that $A$ is diagonal. Now, let $B = e_je_i^\top + e_ie_j^\top$. Then $B=B^\top$, $Be_i = e_j$ and $Be_j = e_i$, and we obtain from $e_j^\top ABe_i = e_j^\top BAe_i$ that $e_j^\top Ae_j = e_i^\top Ae_i$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots,n$. Thus, $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

**Proof 2.** It is easily seen that also $AB = BA$ holds for all $B\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$. Let $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ (a solution of the characteristic equation) and $x\in\mathbb C^n$ a corresponding eigenvector. Then $Ax = \lambda x$ and hence $ABx = BAx = \lambda Bx$ for all $B\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$. Now, since for any $y\in\mathbb R^n$ there exists $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $Bx = y$ (e.g., $Bz = \|x\|^{-2}\langle z,x\rangle y$), we conclude that $Ay = \lambda y$ for all $y\in\mathbb R^n$ and thus $A = \lambda I$.